# adding and deleting div dynamically on click on x button inside a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

On clicking on add button in html page a div should be displayed on html page and multiple div should be shown on multiple clicks. Each div should have X icon and on clicking x, div should disappear from UI. Also it should maintain an array of id's of the dynamically generated div elements which should be shown on console and that id should be deleted whenever that particular div is removed.

This code is working fine but instead of using counter can i use array in which dynamically id will be generated whenever the div is created and id should be removed when div is deleted.?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to make a Division element.</p>

<button id="button" onclick="myFunctionAdd()">Add</button>

<div id="myDIV">
</div>

<script>

 var counter=1;
function myFunctionAdd() 
    {

    var x = document.createElement("DIV");
    x.id="div"

    var divNumber = counter;
    counter++;
    console.log("Div Number: "+ divNumber + " is created");

    var z= document.createElement("button");
    z.id="btn";
    x.setAttribute("style", "border :1px solid;height: 250px; width: 250px; top: 741px; left: 491px; padding:10px; margin: 50px;");
    z.setAttribute("style", "background: #000 url(/home/subodh/Desktop/Widget/icon_incorrect.svg) no-repeat 0px 0px; height: 30px; width:40px; top: 6px; left: 4px; float: right; margin: 0px; padding:0px; clear: both; float:right;");


    x.appendChild(z);
    document.body.appendChild(x).appendChild(z);

    z.onclick = function remove(btn) 
    {

    console.log("Div Number: "+ divNumber + " is deleted");
    x.parentElement.removeChild(x);
    }

   }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read this and aks again https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what did you try? did you search on the web? i'm sure this was answered dozens on times

Comment: have you tired something and failed? if yes, put in the code please...

Comment: Sounds like a shopping list: AngularJS: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_application.asp

Comment: @PrashanthBenny you can now refer to my code and question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this example: https://codepen.io/dsomekh/pen/GEVNWb

```js
function Clone() {


  var clone = document.getElementById('thediv').cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(clone);
}

function Delete(button) {
  var parent = button.parentNode;
  var grand_father = parent.parentNode;
  grand_father.removeChild(parent);
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="mydiv" id="thediv">
    I am the div
    <button type="button" onclick="Clone()" ) ">Clone</button>
      <button type="button " onclick="Delete(this) ")">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Also in this code i want to show unique id of each div in console whenever they are created and that id should be removed whenever that particular div is removed.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```js
function adddiv() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div id=' + Math.random() + '><button id="btn" onclick=closediv(this)>X</button>' + Math.random() + '</div>';
}

function closediv(e) {
  var par = $(event.target).parent();
  par.remove();
}
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}

#btn {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add" onclick=adddiv()>Add</button>
```

now all div created with unique id and using javascript

Comment: Also in this code i want to show unique id of each div in console whenever they are created and that id should be removed whenever that particular div is removed.

Comment: i have updated my answer now div generated with unique id check it @maggie

Comment: It would have been better if this answer is provided in javascript as i dnt know jquery :)

Comment: now all div created with unique id and using javascript @maggie

Comment: But now your closeDiv method is not working . I think you forgot to edit it into javascript. it's still in jQuery.

Comment: bro its properly work you check properly  @maggie

Comment: No it's not. when i am clicking on "x" sign the div is not getn deleted

Comment: you run code snippet bro

Comment: It's giving this error in console :- ReferenceError: event is not defined